# Returning Promises from React 360 Native Module

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React 360 project. All I want to do is pass a value from the main browser window (defined by an attribute within a div) to React at initialisation.

There is a section called "Exposing Constants to React" in the documentation about Native Modules, which I have tried to follow, here: https://facebook.github.io/react-360/docs/native-modules.html

However, all I got was a bunch of "undefined" values. I did a bit of searching and came across the following issue which explains that because Native Modules are called across an asynchronous bridge, you need to return a Promise: https://github.com/facebook/react-360/issues/193

Okay.

I have written a Native Module that returns a Promise. It appears to work correctly internally. The correct value is retrieved from the HTML, and the execution path hits the resolve statement. A separate React Component gets the Promise from the Native Module via a function with a $ added to the front of it, and the Promise itself displays in the console, although I'm not sure if it's well-formed.

*My problem is that the callback functions passed to .then() and .catch() are never executed*. Here is my native module:

```
import {Module} from 'react-360-web'

export default class DataModule extends Module {

    constructor() {
        super('DataModule')
    }

    $getPromise() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var dataValue = document.getElementById('vrContainer').getAttribute('data')
            console.log('internal promise data: ', dataValue)
            if(dataValue !== undefined) {
                console.log('we are resolving')
                resolve(dataValue)
            } else {
                reject(Error("Couldn't get data value"))
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And here is my Component that is trying to get the value:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Environment, NativeModules } from 'react-360'

class Experience extends React.Component {

....

    componentDidMount() {
        var promise = NativeModules.DataModule.getPromise()    
        promise
          .then(result => {
            console.log('it worked: ', result)
          })
          .catch(result => {
            console.log('it didnt: ', result)
          })
    }
```

Neither the 'it worked' or 'it didnt' results are printed to the console, of which I have included a picture here:
[image]

There is some documentation about returning Promises from Native Modules in the first link I provided, but it seems incomplete. It might possibly be related to _ctx and _rnctx but I don't know.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it should be `var promise = NativeModules.DataModule.getPromise` and `promise().then()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, and the behaviour remains the same: callbacks are still not executed. Only change is the structure of the promise variable in the console.